# Branch tracked from a remote

Tags: git, branch

For an application, I needed to know the branch tracked from a remote.

I know how to create a branch that is not on local from a remote :

```
git checkout -t remote/branch
```

I know how to get the remote of a local branch :

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name branch@{u}
```

But now, I need to know with a remote if a branch is tracked with and if yes which one.

For example if I've a branch named test and its remote is toto/hello, I want a command with only 'toto/hello' to give that returns me test.

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something around

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(if:equals=toto/hello)%(upstream:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(else)%(end)' refs/heads
```

or

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(if:equals=toto/hello)%(push:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(else)%(end)' refs/heads
```

?

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-if) for the conditional statements in for-each-ref formats)

Comment: Note that this may list multiple branch names, since you can set the upstream of many branches to one particular name. (That's not a *wise* thing to do, it's just *possible*. :-) )

Comment: @torek D'oh ... you're right. For a manually typed command, no big trouble, but it's a bit clunkier in a script using the output of this...